# White corners at Fancybox on Border Radius

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am applying Border radius on Fancybox http://jsfiddle.net/LF27m/2/ and when i set border radius it creates white corners on Fancybox. and I do not how to remove this.

My css code is :

```
#a1 div.popup-container{
height:350px;
width:400px;
background:#88B3D1;
-moz-border-radius:30px 30px 30px 30px; 
border-radius:30px 30px 30px 30px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

My HTML COde is:

```
<div id="a1">
    <div class="popup-container">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="AllureFree Logo.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="130" height="130"/>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div>
            <h2 style="text-align:center; color:white;"> You must be 18 to shop on our Website.</h2>
            <h2 style="text-align:center; color:white;"> Please verify your birthdate.</h2>
        </div>
</div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are coming from the styles applied to the `.fancybox-skin` selector (fancybox css file). You can override the default values in your custom css file like :

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

also add `padding: 0` to your fancybox script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').append('<a class="fancybox" style="display:none" href="#a1"></a>');
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        afterClose: function () {
            $('a[href="#a1"]').remove();
        }
    });
    $('a[href="#a1"]').trigger('click');
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a33Ax/)**